# how to call an AppDelegate method from RootViewController without passing a delegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

how to call an AppDelegate method from RootViewController without passing a delegate?

Just wondering whether there is a way to do this?  (or do I need to create a delegate object in the RootViewController to hold a reference to the AppDelegate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] someMethod];
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: thanks Daniel - and there's nothing wrong with using this to call methods that are in the AppDelegate (saveCoreData method in my case)?  i.e. there's nothing about this being against best-practice or anything?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you will get compiler warnings if you are calling a custom method defined in your app delegate class without casting it properly.

Comment: Personally, I do not like this way of working with the App-Delegate as it hardwires your calling viewController to the implementation of the app-specific App-Delegate, significantly reducing the reusability of your calling viewController for other projects. So if you asked me, dont do that but define a proper protocol or use NSNotification.

Comment: @Till i agree with that but it depends on the size of the project. Time spent on design and architecture must like any other thing be proportional to the scale of the project, if i was making a throwaway app that takes a day to finish, i probably wouldn't mind coupling classes together.

Answer (score 6):

You can get access to the app delegate from any controller using

```
MyDelegate* aDelegate = (MyDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens so frequently, that I always add a method to `MyCustomAppDelegate` to do this for me (so I don't have a lot of casting in my code.

```
@implementation MyCustomAppDelegate ()
- (MyCustomAppDelegate *)appDelegate {
  return (MyCustomAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
@end
```

now anywhere i can call

```
[MyCustomAppDelgate appDelegate]
```